# Force JUL with clojure.tools.logging

Tags: clojure, java.util.logging

My Clojure app needs to log through Java.Util.Logging (JUL) because custom log rotation is no supported at the moment with Elastic Beanstalk. I'm using clojure.tools.logging to write the log files, but the library keeps auto-selecting log4j as the logging engine.

How can I force clojure.tools.logging to use JUL?

I found a thread online that has a solution using alter-var-root to permanently bind the selected factory to *logger-factory*:

```
(alter-var-root (var log/*logger-factory*) (constantly (impl/jul-factory)))
```

...but it's an older thread and didn't know if there was a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this one every day:

```
(alter-var-root                   
 #'clojure.tools.logging/*logger-factory*   
 (constantly (clojure.tools.logging.slf4j/load-factory))
```

switching slf4j for impl/jul-factory should be reliable and at least mostly sane.